# Detect a specific update_user_meta in Worpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I would like to code a Wordpress/WooCommerce plugin launching a function every time this is called :

```
update_user_meta($user_id,'mwb_wpr_points',$nomber_of_points);
```

But I don't know which hook I should use and how to use it.

Answer (score 2):

A similar question was asked [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/301205/detect-change-to-user-meta-and-retrieve-old-and-new-values).

The answer states that the `insert_user_meta` filter needs to be used.

I haven't tested the below code, but I believe the value being updated will be stored in the `$_POST`.  You can check against the existing value to determine if that field is being updated.  Hopefully this is enough to get your started.

```
add_filter('insert_user_meta', 'my_updated_user_meta', 10, 3);
function my_updated_user_meta($meta, $user, $update) {

     // if not updating the field, because it is a create, do nothing  
     if( true !== $update ) {
          return $meta;
      }


      $old_meta = get_user_meta( $user->ID );
      if(isset($_POST['mwb_wpr_points']) && isset($old_meta['mwb_wpr_points']))
          if($old_meta['mwb_wpr_points'][0] !== $_POST['mwb_wpr_points']) {

              // mwb_wbr_points has been updated.
              // do your code here

          }
      }

      return $meta;
}
```